# My filtered data keeps returning data it shouldn't return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to filter blocked users from a list of chats. It returns the correct list when I use "===" to display users that are blocked. But when I use "!==", it returns users that aren't blocked and users that are blocked. It only excludes one blocked user and returns the rest. What can I do?

Here's my code...

```
const checkBlockedUsers = async () => {
    const blockedUsersList:any = []
    const blockedUsersRef = collection(db, `users`, auth.currentUser?.uid, `blockedUsers`)
    getDocs(blockedUsersRef).then(blockedUsers => {
      blockedUsers.docs.map(blockedUser => {
        blockedUsersList.push(blockedUser.data().blockedUser.id)
      })
    }).then(() => {
      blockedUsersList.map(blockedUserId => {
            onSnapshot(query(collection(db, `convos`, convoId, `chats`), orderBy(`timestamp`, `asc`)), snapshot => {
              const filteredData = snapshot.docs.filter(doc => doc.data().user.id === blockedUserId)
              filteredData.map(doc => {
                console.log(doc.data().user.username)
              })
            }) 

          }
        )
    })
    
  }
```

I want it to exclude all blocked users from the list of chats. And not exclude just one blocked user

Comment: Why are you using two `then` callbacks?  You only need one since there is only one promise in use returned by `getDocs`. Also there is nothing stopping the listener created by the call to `onSnapshot`, so it will just keep running indefinitely.  Are you sure you didn't want to use `getDocs` again?

Comment: Really just a beginner in web development but I'll correct it. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what I can do to resolve the filter issue?

Comment: We can't tell for sure because we can't see the data you're working with - we don't know what is actually happening when this code runs.  Your question should contain everything necessary for someone to fully reproduce the problem as you observe it.

Comment: I'm using onSnapshot because getDocs would not update the chats in real-time. Or would it?

Comment: The goal of the code is to check for blocked users once a user enters a chatroom and then exclude all blocked users' chats before setting the chats state using the filtered data. I unfortunately can't provide the data because it's up on Google's firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're making so many asynchronous calls inside a loop, and by the time the callbacks within the loop executed, the loop may have been already completed.

1. To fix this use await so that each function runs one after another to get proceeded.
2. I used Array.includes to filter the chats to see if the user is in the blocked users list

```
const checkBlockedUsers = async () => {
 try {
   const blockedUsersList = [];

   const blockedUsersRef = collection(db, 'users', auth.currentUser?.uid, 'blockedUsers');
   const blockedUsersSnapshot = await getDocs(blockedUsersRef);

   blockedUsersSnapshot.forEach((blockedUser) => {
     blockedUsersList.push(blockedUser.data().blockedUser.id);
   });

   const chatsRef = query(collection(db, 'convos', convoId, 'chats'), orderBy('timestamp', 'asc'));
   const chatsSnapshot = await getDocs(chatsRef);

   const filteredChats = chatsSnapshot.docs.filter((doc) => {
     return !blockedUsersList.includes(doc.data().user.id);
   });

   filteredChats.forEach((doc) => {
     console.log(doc.data().user.username);
   });
 } catch (error) {
   console.error('Error:', error);
 }
};
```

Hope this works
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate. It works!!